# Should the 'type="module"' declaration be removed from an html <script> tag after the associated Firebase source has been bundled?

Tags: javascript, firebase

A javascript file containing `import` statements referencing Firebase browser modules embedded in an HTML file needs to be declared as `type="module"`. But after conversion to ES6 modules, this qualifier seems to be optional.

Is a "bundled" javascript file no longer regarded as a module? It certainly still behaves like a module, at least in the sense that a Javascript function in your bundled file remains unavailable to the DOM (eg, an "onclick" reference to a bundled function won't work).

Examples of  tags in Google documents seem to confirm the pattern - scripts using browser modules should be declared `type="module"`, bundled scripts should be left unqualified. But what exactly is going on here?

Advice would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, before you build an app, i.e. before you do `npm run build`, remove type="module" from all the script tags.

What happens under the hood is that the bundler puts all the code from your .js files into one big file.
You can find that file inside you dist folder.

If you're using Webpack or Parcel or any other bundler, they convert JS from ES6+ to ES5, and ES5 does not support import statements, that is why it puts all the js code into one big file.

Comment: The thing is though that the bundled file still seems to have its own namepsace - so it's still a module. I think what's going on here is that because your webpacked file doesn't include "imports" anymore it just doesn't matter whether you declare it as type module or not..